# Next and Previous records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my show.html.erb file I have two links for next and previous like so

```
<%= link_to("Previous Post", @question.previous) if @question.previous %>
<%= link_to("Next Post", @question.next) if @question.next %>
```

.previous and .next are methods in my model which finds either the current id + 1 or - 1

like so in my model

```
def previous
  Question.find_by_id(id - 1, :select => 'id')
end

def next
  Question.find_by_id(id + 1, :select => 'id')
end
```

But rather than incrementing and decrementing blindly as I might have deleted a "Question" so i'll get an error, could I find the next/previous "Question" from the scope of the query the show action was accessed from?

Comment: I feel like it would be far better to just fetch all the questions you need from the database in one go...

Comment: doesn't active record have a "query history" you can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
def previous
  Question.limit(1).order("id DESC").where("id < ?", id)
end

def next
  Question.limit(1).order("id DESC").where("id > ?", id)
end
```

Comment: looked like the one but it's giving me the following error `undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class`

Comment: Add `.first` to the end of the queries

Answer (score 0):

Try Act as Ordered.
https://github.com/imedo/acts_as_ordered

Comment: acts as ordered is for rails 2.1, i'm on 3.1 (forgot to mention that)